# Why doesn't Java create a file with the system time in it's filename?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I'm working on a Bukkit/Spigot plugin for my Minecraft server. This command is supposed to create a file with the system time in it and whatever the player puts in for an argument. For some reason, it doesn't work. It has to do with what is in the filename.

Printing out `networkfolder + File.separator + filename` gives me `C:\Users\Anston Sorensen\Desktop\Minecraft Servers\Sun Apr 24 20:40:41 CDT 2022-D.txt`. What could be going on?

My command class:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;

            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You need to enter some arguments");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "To save the server network to the GitHub website: /saveserver <what you built/did(TYPE _ FOR SPACES)>");
            } else if (args.length == 1) {
                File curdir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                Path parentfolder = curdir.toPath().getParent().getParent();
                String networkfolder = parentfolder + File.separator + "Minecraft Servers";
                Date date = new Date();
                String filename = date + "-" + args[0].toUpperCase().replace("_", " ") + ".txt";

                File txt = new File(networkfolder + File.separator + filename);
                try {
                    txt.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    player.sendMessage("Unable to create file.");
                }
            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Too many arguments");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "To save the server network to the GitHub website: /saveserver <what you built/did(TYPE _ FOR SPACES)>");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
[15:18:44 WARN]: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1043)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at CrucialPlugin-1.0.jar//me.acclashcorporation.crucialplugin.commands.TestCrap.onCommand(TestCrap.java:36)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:906)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:2306)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:2117)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:2098)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:46)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:6)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$ensureRunningOnSameThread$1(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:51)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(TickTask.java:18)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.d(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:153)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.d(IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.java:24)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1399)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.d(MinecraftServer.java:188)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.y(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:126)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.be(MinecraftServer.java:1376)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:1369)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.c(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:136)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:1347)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1229)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:315)
[15:18:44 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Print out the String `networkfolder + File.separator + filename` before you create the file.  What does it have in it?

Comment: Use your debugger to look at `txt` before the call to `createNewFile()`.  There may be some unexpected characters in there, such as two slashes in a row, or similar.

Comment: @stdunbar It gives me this: C:\Users\Anston Sorensen\Desktop\Minecraft Servers\Sun Apr 24 20:40:41 CDT 2022-D.txt

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem There isn't

Comment: That isn't a valid Windows file name @ThrownRedstone.  See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for details but the extra colon characters are breaking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, the filename syntax is incorrect.

```
C:\Users\Anston Sorensen\Desktop\Minecraft Servers\Sun Apr 24 20:40:41 CDT 2022-D.txt
```

You can't use colons in Windows filenames, except for after the drive letter.  You need to rethink your name generation strategy.